# Display value of Hexa stored in Array

Tags: c++

I have and array of hexa values called 
 const char receiptLogo[] = {0x01,0x80,0x00,0xB4};

When I tried to get the value Rprintf("%x\r\n",receiptLogo[3]);

Value was displayed as "ffffffb4" and sometimes it was displayed as "b4"

The whole Function is as
void PRINT_PrintLogo( const char Data[])
{

```
unsigned int  height=0;

const char receiptLogo[] = {0x01,0x80,0x00,0xB4};
height=(((unsigned short)receiptLogo[2] ) << 8) | ((unsigned short)receiptLogo[3] );
Rprintf("height=%d,%x,%x\r\n",height,Data[2],Data[3]);
```

}

The output of this function is
height=65460,0,ffffffb4

although in other times the output is height=180,0,b4

Kindly please advise the reason behind it

Comment: Which output do you expect to see?

Comment: "b4" but why sometimes "b4" and another times "ffffffb4"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit simply that what was happing with me that is why i opened a case , because it wired that when execute your code and value is dsiaplyed as Only "b4" and you compile again ad run the same code the value is displayed as "ffffffb4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in printf() the %X format specifier is hexadecimal int.  If you pass a char as a parameter and the most significant bit is set it should sign extend to fill the size of an integer.  The compiler may optimize by packing variables and sometimes your variable my be in different places with respect to byte boundaries (i.e. the char may end up in the least significant byte or most significant byte of a 32-bit integer).  This access may cause this behavior.

Comment: Thank. But the array must be char. Please assist me how can I resolve the issue

Comment: You can mask off the upper bits:  Rprintf("height=%d,%x,%x\r\n",height,Data[2] & 0xFF,Data[3] & 0xFF);

Comment: Ah yes of course - there _isn't_ a conversion... `unsigned int` is _expected_. C variadics get me every time.

Comment: Thank you. I did that but really it cause big damage and conflict that is why I need to understand the reason of that fault

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you. you mean I should convert to unsigned int instead of unsigned short?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have unsigned int instead of unsigned short and I got the same result.\

Comment: @TimDave when I mask the upper bits it works fine. But I need to know it's compiler issue or something is wrong in the code?
Thank you

Comment: The code is correct.  It is an implicit type conversion from a smaller  type (char) to larger type (unsigned int).  The code is safe, you are just seeing artifacts of the conversion.